# Accessing SQL database in iOS app

Tags: objective-c, sql, ios, macos, cocoa-touch

I have an SQL database stored in my server, and I want my iOS app to access it. It contains passwords and such, and I need the app to be able to download the contents. What is the best way of doing this? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you have two options.

- Firstly you can directly access your DB via HTTP requests and get the data that you want.
  (Not the suggested way.)
- Or you can create a Web service which communicates with your DB and acts as a layer between  your app and db.You can either get the all data or the ones you want from DB depending on your Web service.